# How can I change the css of a day cell by date?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In a `dayClick` event, I can change the CSS of the current cell using `this` as shown in the [fullcalendar documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/). For example, I just have to do `$(this).css('background-color', 'red');`

Assuming I have a date stored as a moment, how can do the same thing outside of the `dayClick` event?

Comment: You mean change the color of a event on fullcalendar render?

Comment: No just the day cell `<td>` DOM node. No event related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`dayRender()`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) method. I know... There isn't that much documentation... Here is a working fiddle of how to change the background color of the current date and all the 7 days after current date using this event:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        var today = $.fullCalendar.moment();
        var end = $.fullCalendar.moment().add(7, 'days');
        
        if (date.get('date') == today.get('date')) {
            cell.css("background-color", "red");
        }
        
        if(date > today && date <= end) {
            cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
      
    }   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/2.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/2.0.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Have also a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) documentation in order to manipulate the date objects.

**EDIT**

I assume you're using fullCalendar v2. For v1 have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613582/fullcalendar-change-the-color-for-specific-days) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920017/change-the-day-background-color-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: I am indeed using the V2. How can I rerun the `dayRender()` at will?

Comment: From the docs: "_This callback is called each time a cell needs to be freshly rendered._" so you need to refetch the events with [`refetchEvents()`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) method

Comment: It does not work. I assume that the cell needs an event to be rerendered. I also tried the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324311/re-draw-fullcalendar-on-the-fly but it didn't work either in my context (I am using meteor).

Comment: I finally managed to get the cell using plain jQuery: `$("td").find("[data-date='" + this.date.format() + "']").css("background-color", "");` I will give you a +1 anyway, but if you want to update your answer, I will validate it as well.

Comment: Yes... That seems the only "workaround" actually for your specific need there's an [openIssue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2709) on GitHub... So no solutions are available atm... Just use plain JQuery... Anyway if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.