# Coloring holidays after an Ajax call in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm working with http://fullcalendar.io/.
My purpose is to give different background color to holidays. After a lot of searches I can say that a good solution is using dayRender hook. But how to fetch holidays list, and what about timing?

Solution 1: an Ajax call for each day.

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myproject/holidays?date='+date,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(isHoliday) {
            if (isHoliday) {
                cell.css("background-color", "red");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It should work but... an Ajax call for EACH days? It seems not a nice solution..

Solution 2: one ajax call to fetch all the holidays

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    if ($.inArray(date, holidayList)) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

where "holidayList" was fetched somewhere before. **That's my problem. Before when?** How can I be sure that holidayList has been completed fetched before each dayRender is called?
In other words: **is there a hook I can rely on to fetch the holidays list?**

Thank you

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613582/fullcalendar-change-the-color-for-specific-days) helpful.

Comment: That answer (which I had already read) does not add anything to my question, It suggests to use "dayRender", which is already mentioned in my question. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I see here:

1. Initialize the whole calendar only after the holiday fetching Ajax request is done (and meanwhile display a loader/spinner). Simple, but not "pretty".
2. As soon as the holiday fetching Ajax request is done, refresh the whole calendar view. As the internal `reinitView` method is sadly not being exported to be called externally, you have to do it in a few more steps:

   ```
   var fcEl = $('#calendar'),
       view = fcEl.fullCalendar('getView');
   view.unrenderDates();
   view.renderDates();
   fcEl.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll go with the first one, not becaus is more simple, but because I don't like the idea of a second fetch, as it may cause flickering events or, worse, the lost of user's action.

Comment: Of course, the table would briefly display without the holiday background colours, depending on how long the ajax request takes, that's true.