# (Fullcalendar) Auto click days using back-end information

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need my Fullcalendar to auto-click two dates, this is how i made my dayClick:

```
 dayClick: function (date) {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(33, 115, 240)') {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'white'
      })
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#2173f0'
      })
    }
  }
```

It works fine, when i click a day, that day becomes blue, when i click it again, it turns white. The thing is, my user is selecting two days in an `<input>` tag, when those days are selected, i need fullcalendar to autoclick those days on itself, so they become blue.

This is the idea:

First you'll see a field where you type in two days, 
fullcalendar will respond and turn those days blue, 
then you'll select some other days using the fullcalendar itself

i wrote something like this:

```
  sendDate(val: any) { //this method will be called the the inputs are filled
    var dataIni =val.metasForm.value.gesMetasDtini;
    var dataFim =val.metasForm.value.gesMetasDtfim;
    //this gets the dates

    if (dataIni != null && dataFim != null) {
     $("#calendar").dayClick(dataIni);
     $("#calendar").dayClick(dataFim);
    }
  }
```

The thing is, this does not really turn those days blue. Is there any other way for me to do it?

EDIT: some more code

the calendar:

```
<div id="form-group" class="left" style="width: 90%">
            <ng-fullcalendar id="calendar"></ng-fullcalendar>
        <br><br>
</div>
```

the input:

```
<div id="form-group" class="left">
    <input id="ini" placeholder="Data de Início" type="text" 
        formControlName="gesMetasDtini" class="form-control" (change)="sendDate(this)">
    <br>
</div>

<div id="form-group" class="right">
    <input id="fim" placeholder="Data de Fim" type="text" 
    formControlName="gesMetasDtfim" class="form-control" (change)="sendDate(this)">
    <br>
</div>
```

The methods:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  //selectable: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  dayClick: function (date) {

   // var DiaSemana = date._d.toString();
   // DiaSemana = DiaSemana.substring(0, 3);

   // if (DiaSemana == 'Sat' || DiaSemana == 'Fri') {
   //   console.log('fim de semana')
   // }

    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(33, 115, 240)') {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'white'
      })
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        'background-color': '#2173f0'
      })
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to past the whole code so we could test and modify the script.

Comment: done, i added some more code

Comment: Try background events to keep a day highlighted in the colour of your choice.

Comment: i dont know which fullcalander script you are using so add the whole things, script css etc we need to run this.

Comment: `$("#calendar").dayClick(` ...there is no such method [documented](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) in fullCalendar, so I'm not sure where you got the idea to use it. There's only the dayClick _callback_. Instead you must target the HTML element itself. Luckily, this element has data describing which day it is. So something like `$('.fc-day[data-date="2019-01-05"').css("background-color", "blue");` will work. Here's a demo which runs that code each time the view renders: http://jsfiddle.net/7nsbjya5/ . All you need to do now is integrate that with your `<input>` control.

Comment: P.S. This is very similar to a previously asked question: [Any way to colorize specific days in FullCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533240/any-way-to-colorize-specific-days-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: thanks @ADyson, it worked, if you post an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: @CH4B done - thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
$("#calendar").dayClick(
```

...there is no such method documented in fullCalendar, so I'm not sure where you got the idea to use it. There's only the dayClick *callback* which you already know about.

Instead you must target the HTML element itself. Luckily, this element has data describing which day it is. So something like

```
$('.fc-day[data-date="2019-01-05"').css("background-color", "blue");
```

will work. Here's a demo which runs that code each time the view renders: http://jsfiddle.net/7nsbjya5 .

All you need to do now is integrate that with your `<input>` control in a suitable way to meet your requirement.